# Ingress no address

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have little k8s cluster in my machine and I try to make something for learn but I stack right now.

I have 2 app, one of mysql and another one wordpress and they are working good. When I give a LoadBalancer type for wordpress, it's taking a ip and I can see in my browser.

So I want to create a Ingress and call by hostname but Ingress not take a Loadbalancer IP..
Am I doing wrong anythin?

This is my Ingress configuration

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wp-ingress
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  labels:
    name: wp-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: wordpress.pandora.local
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: wp-svc
            port: 
              number: 80
  - host: phpmyadmin.pandora.local
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: phpmyadmin-svc
            port: 
              number: 80
```

and problem

```
# kg ingress
NAME         CLASS    HOSTS                                              ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
wp-ingress   <none>   wordpress.pandora.local,phpmyadmin.pandora.local             80      38m
```

I'm using a Metallb for loadbalancer and I know it's work becasue of wordpress, but if you want to see

```
kg svc -A
NAMESPACE          NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
calico-apiserver   calico-api                           ClusterIP      10.108.149.243   <none>           443/TCP                      45h
calico-system      calico-kube-controllers-metrics      ClusterIP      10.100.211.40    <none>           9094/TCP                     45h
calico-system      calico-typha                         ClusterIP      10.107.217.253   <none>           5473/TCP                     45h
default            kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>           443/TCP                      45h
default            mysql-svc                            ClusterIP      10.103.110.242   <none>           3306/TCP                     3h1m
default            phpmyadmin-svc                       ClusterIP      10.105.195.144   <none>           80/TCP                       156m
default            wp-svc                               ClusterIP      10.100.96.37     <none>           80/TCP                       126m
ingress-nginx      ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.99.196.206    192.168.188.20   80:30986/TCP,443:32709/TCP   49m
ingress-nginx      ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.99.212.249    <none>           443/TCP                      49m
kube-system        kube-dns                             ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>           53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       45h
```

How can I troubleshoot the situation

Comment: I really don't understand this. When I entered a reply with "answer your question" recently, someone warned me that I need to add first post. Now the opposite is said. Which one is right? @ArnavThorat

Comment: Adding an answer is better for readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved. Thank for help :)
The problem was about to ingress class.

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wp-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: wordpress.pandora.local
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: wp-svc
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: phpmyadmin.pandora.local
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: phpmyadmin-svc
            port:
              number: 80
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

I added the last line *ingressClassName: nginx* defination and it's work!

```
kg ingress
NAME         CLASS   HOSTS                                              ADDRESS         PORTS   AGE
wp-ingress   nginx   wordpress.pandora.local,phpmyadmin.pandora.local   192.168.88.20   80      5h19m
```

Comment: Damn why the templet generator don't add this by default !

Answer (score 0):

Even though there's already an accepted answer here, I wanted to show steps on troubleshooting this issue.

### Full source code [here](https://github.com/akhanalcs/k8s-hands-on).

### Step 1

Check your ingress.

```
kubectl get ingress -n local
```

You'll see that the controller hasn't assigned any address to the hostname.

[image]

### Step 2

Ensure you have installed Ingress Controller. Follow instructions [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

### Step 3

Check the ingress controller logs. I'm using Kubernetes dashboard here. You can use `kubectl` if you'd like.
The error will tell you the problem.

[image]

This is the error seen in the logs:

```
"Ignoring ingress because of error while validating ingress class" ingress="local/test-app-release-test-app-api" error="ingress does not contain a valid IngressClass"
```

### Step 4

Find the `IngressClass`. You can get this by either running this command: `kubectl get ingressclasses` or finding it through K8s dashboard.

**Command way:**
[image]

**Dashboard way:**
[image]

### Step 5

Update your ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-app-release-test-app-api
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: test-app-api-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: test-app-api
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: test-app-release
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx    # <------ THIS GUY
  rules:
    - host: "chart-example.local"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /my-test-app(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: test-app-release-test-app-api
                port:
                  number: 80
```

### Step 6

Deploy the app. At this point, you'll be able to see the address assigned by the controller.

```
kubectl get ingress -n local
```

[image]